# Find all factors of a number [JS]

Tags: javascript, factors

in javascript also put them in an array I want it to be a function thank you

example: `12 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12`

`5 = 1, 5`

`7326 = 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 11, 18, 22, 33, 37...` etc

I tried this:

```
let factors = [];


const find = num => {

 for(i=0;i<=i/2;i++){
  if(num%i==0){
  factors.push(num/i);
  }
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate(num) {
    var factorArr = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) { 
           factorArr.push(i);
        }
    }
    console.log(factorArr);
}

calculate(5);
```

Comment: As an optimization, you only need to go upto the sqrt of num.